# Механизм сообщений в сервере

Tags: python, twisted, архитектура, сервер, сокет

Пишу игровой сервер на twisted, дошел до части, когда нужно сделать механизм событий. 
Этот механизм должен создавать какие-либо события, которые должны произойти в будущем. Например, игрок решил построить здание, здание построится через час. Соответственно через час должно произойти событие "постройка"; его можно отменить. Таких событий может быть очень много, за всеми ими нужно следить и сообщать об окончании и отменять. 
Вопрос следующий, как примерно это организовать? Есть какие либо статьи или примеры?

Comment: не знаю, как это конкретно делается в питоне, но вообще обычно так:
в каждом событии заводишь счетчик.
раз в некоторое время dt (обычно неск секунд) обходишь список всех событий и счетчик каждого уменьшаешь на dt. если счетчик события стал меньше нуля, то выполняешь событие.
второй вариант (чуть более общий и чуть менее быстрый): заранее рассчитываешь время, когда должно произойти событие (удобно заюзать unixtime) и, опять же, периодически сравниваешь это время для каждого события со временем на сервере.
после выполнения событие (как правило) выбрасывается из списка событий.
вот собсно и всё.

Comment: Если событий ОЧЕНЬ много, то можно особым образом организовать список и обходить его лишь частично. Например, разбить его на подсписки: "события, которые должны произойти менее чем через 10 минут", "события, которые должны произойти через 10-20 минут" и т.д.. Можно использовать и другие способы разбиения списка (например: "события, которые следует проверять как можно чаще", "события, которые следует проверять хотя бы раз в минуту" и т.п.)

Comment: Спасибо, alphard, могли и как ответ оформить. Мне в голову пришел только второй ваш вариант, но я начала беспокоиться что каждый пробег по списку тоже забирает время. То есть вполне можно опоздать к свершению какого либо события. Как раз второй ваш вариант мне кажется сильно быстрее первого. Разделение на группы отличная идея только этими группами, такими как в вашем описании, придется тоже управлять. Перебрасывая из события "которые должны произойти через 10-20 минут" в "менее чем через 10 минут" в нужный момент, то есть еще перебор всех групп на фоне...

Comment: можно не разбивать на группы, а просто сортировать список по времени событий. и обрывать цикл на отдаленном времени. но на сортировку будет что-то уходить тоже. рад, что чем-то помог, в отдельный ответ не выделял, т.к. думал, что вопрос более python-specific:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В twisted нашелся метод для таких вещей

```
reactor.callLater(3600, createBuilding)
```

через 60 минут будет выполнена функция createBuilding, подробней [тут](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/time.html).

Comment: Ключевой момент — а если сервер рухнет?

Comment: рухнул == паника=)
Класть описание задачи в бд/файл , и после того как оно сделано, удалять из файла/бд.  При инициации севера смотреть в эти файлы/бдшки, вызвать нужные callLater или если уже наступили то createBuilding. - вот так я думал когда пытался все сделать на deferreds.
В реальности оказалось что для какой либо существенной нагрузки это не применимо, 100-1000 таких дефередов еще ок, а далее существенная нагрузка на проц.

Answer (score 1):

(Ответ запоздалый, хех, но почему бы и нет? На SO было незазорно давать ответы и к старым вопросам, т.к. вики же.)

Я бы предложил строить отсортированный список-очередь (можно [с пропусками](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8), чтобы удешевить вставку) и смотрите, скажем, раз в секунду, в его конец (`O(1)`) не пора ли обрабатывать очередное событие. Пришло время — забирайте из списка (опять же, `O(1)`) элементы, пока не наткнетесь на очередной элемент, время которого пока не пришло.

В итоге имеем вставку за `O(log n)` (и то, можно попытаться еще оптимизировать, держа «указатели» на типичные места вставок типа «через 60 минут», и обновлять их когда вставляем/забираем, сделав некоторые вставки за `O(1)`), и выборку очередного события (оно же — проверку не пора ли что-то делать) за `O(1)`.